# Installing apache osx mountain lion dont interpret php

Tags: php, apache, osx-mountain-lion

Looked in many places and done many times all processes described. I managed to configure apache however he does not interpret the files in php. It displays the

Php installed, rename the php.ini, I removed the # configuration of apache, restart apache ... nothing.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You havent given us enough information. Did you uncomment the LoadModule lines? Did you uncomment/add the AddType and AddHandler directives for PHP resources?

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you've added following to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

<IfModule php5_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
  AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps

  <IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

If yes, check your apache error log and see if there's any errors.